# Мне нужен механизм, авто замены команд в тексте, на данные из базы данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, linq, лексический-анализатор

Мне нужен механизм, авто замены команд в тексте, на данные из базы данных.
К примеру:

"Пользователь: "{[User.Name]}" Возраст: "{[User.Age]}"
Покупки:
{Название: "[User.Purchases.Name]" Стоймость: "[User.Purchases.Price]"}"

Результат:

"Пользователь: "Роман" Возраст: 69
Покупки:

- Название: "Хлеб" Стоймость : 48р
- Название: "Сыр" Стоймость : 261р
- Название: "Помидоры"" Стоймость : 180р

Или

"Пользователи купившие привилегии:
{Имя: "[Users( Where Role != default ).Name]" Роль: "[Users( Where Role != default ).Role]"}"

Результат:
"Пользователи купившие привилегии

- Имя: "Евген"  Роль: "Доминатор"
- Имя: "Валера" Роль: "Царь"
- Имя: "Егорыч" Роль: "Бог""

Comment: ну вон есть же всякие [razor](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/generate-outputs-with-razor-engine-in-dotnet-core), которые принимают модель и из неё рисуют html, который по сути текстовый. Нелья его прикрутить к вашей задаче?

Comment: Проблемма в том что мы не используем вэб языки и платформы.  нам необходимо другой подход. мы используем ADO.NET и entity-framework.

Comment: причем тут веб языки? Razor - это движок шаблонов. Он заточен на генерацию HTML, но может и строки генерировать. Я ссылку оставил, почитайте её.

Comment: ну или вон, [при правильном запросе](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+string+template+engine), гугл выдает пачку вариантов

Comment: Благодарю, будем разбиратся :)